# JQuery replace class with id

Tags: jquery

I want to replace every instance of class readMore across the entire page with id btn-2018.

Should be very easy I thought

```js
   $('.readMore').attr('id', 'btn-2018');
$('#btn-2018').removeClass('readMore');
```

For some reason loading that script only replaces the first instance.

Comment: you cannot use same id for multiple elements. Either try replacing  unique id for each `readMore` or try some different appraoch

Comment: The id should be unique in the same document.

Comment: If you pass an ID as a selector jQuery will stop searching as soon as it finds the first element. Because, as others have mentioned, IDs _must_ be unique in the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run each item on a jQuery loop, then apply id, while removing class on each iteration.

```
$('.readMore').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('id', 'btn-2018');
    $(this).removeClass('readMore');
});
```

If you want dynamically generated id, you can try one below:

```
var i = 0;
$('.readMore').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('id', 'btn-' + i);
    $(this).removeClass('readMore');
    i++;
});
```

Comment: Ids have to be **unqiue**

Comment: I know. But OP didn't specify if id is generated by something.

Comment: So you're adding an answer that doesn't make much sense, because...?

Comment: @Andreas wether it makes sense or not, this is what OP asked for. The answer is still correct.

Comment: @Andreas OP wanted to replace every instance of class `readMore` across the entire page with id `btn-2018`. My answer does what he wants.

Comment: Also no need for a `each()` function. jQuery is build to do chaining on lists of elements. Though it would be wise to use an iterator number to add to the id. Then you will need a loop.

Comment: @kgbph Well your answer would be better if you edit an iteration number in to make the id's actually unique.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, but you really don't want to for multiple elements. Id's need to be unique in html.

```js
$('.readmore').attr('id', 'btn-2018').removeClass('readMore');

$('p').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="readmore">Read more..</p>
<p class="readmore">Read more..</p>
```

Comment: _"...that script only replaces the first instance"_ - So there's clearly more than one element

Comment: @Andreas That's why I said he shouldn't want that.

Answer (score 0):

When using the id you get only the first element with that id (because the id is made to be unique).
If you want to remove the class from all of the elements use the class, just like with the attribute - 
`$('.readMore').removeClass('readMore');`

But, as I mentioned, you shouldn't have the same id for more than one element. Maybe you should use another class, or add a number to the id so it would be unique ("btn-2018-1", "btn-2018-2" etc).